# R Lapply PointsOnLines thru a list of psp objects

Tags: r, spatstat

Now that I have successfully, thanks to @Phil, coerced my SpatialLinesDataFrame into a list of list of psp objects, I need to use the SpatStat function pointsOnLines to create points along each list item(ie. Line), and have the marks of the line transferred to each set of points.

Im new to lapply, but seeing how it was used in converting the spatialdataframe to a list of psp objects, I think its appropriate to use it to apply the pointsOnLines function to each list?  Alas, It isn't working for me.  Help!

To continue the fylk example....

```
library("maptools")
library("rgdal")
library("spatstat")

base_dir <- system.file("shapes", package = "maptools")
fylk <- readOGR(base_dir, "fylk-val")

is(fylk)

out <- lapply(fylk@lines, function(i) { lapply(i@Lines, as.psp) })
out

dat <- fylk@data
for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(dat))) {
  out[[i]] <- lapply(out[[i]], "marks<-", value = dat[i, , drop = FALSE])
}

for(i in seq_along(out)){
  abc[[i]]<-(lapply(out[[i]],function(i){pointsOnLines(out[[i]],eps=10)}))
}
```

This doesnt work, and i can't troubleshoot why.  I used [[]] as out is a list of lists?

Suggestions for the newbie?

Comment: *This doesnt work* ... is never helpful for us. What is the error or undesired result? I see you never initialize `abc` and you are passing `out[[i]]` inside the anonymous function. Remember `i` becomes the object to be used when passed into `function()`. Also, you are re-using `i` in both the `for` and `lapply` loops.

Comment: You are making things more complicated for yourself than necessary. Refer to my answer to your previous question and make the lines into a `linnet`. Then you have direct access to spatstat functions to generate points on the network etc. Look at functions called something with lpp and lines in spatstat. Best reference is chapter 17 of the spatstat book. Writing from my phone so can't look up all the names for you. Look at help files for `linnet` and `lpp` and the references to other functions therein. Good luck.

Comment: @EgeRubak An object of class "linnet" represents a network of straight line segments in two dimensions. I do not have straight line segments but very curvy arcs.  Therefor, I don't think your suggestion will help me.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Parfait Your right, I will provide the error received in the future. Im very new to R, and self taught so its a steep learning curve. The solution posted below did run, however it wasn't the desired outcome.  I need a psp object of points along the lines contained within a list object.  the error code I recieve when I run the code you provided, and then try to plot the result is this...```Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'```

Comment: A psp and a SpatialLines object are also just straight line segments like linnet. You can represent the same lines in these classes. The advantage of linnet is that it knows which segments are connected in intersections and allow for paths to go from one segment to another. Typically curved arcs are represented by many small straight lines glued together. These can be represented by all three classes. If you have truly curved arcs not represented by collections of straight lines your are out of luck with anything in spatstat (and R in general I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last `lapply` is your issue, consider a nested `lapply` to assign the result to `abc`:

```
abc <- lapply(out, function(o)
           lapply(o, function(x) pointsOnLines(x, eps=10))
           # EQUIVALENTLY:
           # lapply(o, pointsOnLines, eps=10)
       )
```

And to plot according to docs, run elementwise loop with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) between `out` and `abc` lists.

One psp and ppp pair:

```
plot(out[[1]], main="")
plot(abc[[1]], add=TRUE, pch="+")
```

Multiple psp and ppp pairs:

```
proc_plot <- function(X, Y) {
    plot(X, main="")
    plot(Y, add=TRUE, pch="+")
}

result <- Map(proc_plot, out, abc)
```

Comment: With your above error, how did you `plot`? Did you plot both psp and ppp objects per example in [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.61-0/topics/pointsOnLines)? You need to do so as `abc` elements are layered on first from `out` list. See extended answer.